# Validate two column exists in a row Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

How to validate two column exists in a row by #Laravel 5.4
Now am doing this like below way :

## My Controller Code :

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'classlevel_id'=>'required',
    'book_name'=>'required|string',
    'class_no'=>'required|integer',
]);
    
if($validator->fails())
{
    return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
}else{
    $valid = DB::table('books')->where('class_no',$request->class_no)->where('book_name',$request->book_name)->exists();
    if($valid){
        return response()->json(['warning'=>"Book : ".$request->book_name." and class : ".$request->class_no." already Exists"]);
    }
}
```

## i also tried to do validate like below way :

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'classlevel_id'=>'required',
    'book_name'=>'required|string|unique:books|required_with:class_no',
    'class_no'=>'required|string|unique:books|required_with:book_name',
]);
```

is there any Laravel Validate command for validate two columns exists in a row?

Answer (score 0):

U have to use Laravel custom Validation rule
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-rule-objects

Comment: Would be nice if you can include some more content instead of being a [link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)!